# How to build llvm-hs from source

Tags: haskell, clang, llvm, cabal

I'm *working on parsing large llvm-ir code using haskell & llvm-hs* for some research work.

I used gllvm (comment on this post - [Getting LLVM IR for a clang/clang++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66719189/getting-llvm-ir-for-a-clang-clang-project)) to convert openssl (libssl) to .bc files and then to .ll using llvm-dis and parsing the .ll file using haskell & llvm-hs.

During this I'm facing this issue - https://github.com/llvm-hs/llvm-hs/issues/282#issue-511780377  -- **Missing Function Attribute "NoFree" #282** & **unhandled function attribute enum value: FunctionAttributeKind 26**
which are basically *edge cases* not handled by llvm-hs in it's release but fixed in this commit - https://github.com/llvm-hs/llvm-hs/pull/284

initially I had installed llvm-hs using `cabal install --lib llvm-hs` what I need help with is **I'm not sure how to build it from source**.

I cloned the llvm-hs repo and checked out to the commit with fix (or latest commit) of branch llvm-9 and added the path of this repo to the $PATH, how do i use cabal to build this from source ? I am working on a small project so it doesn't have a project file or a .cabal file

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a cabal project that depends on llvm-hs and use https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-project.html#specifying-packages-from-remote-version-control-locations to specify the commit.

Note that since that PR is pulling from a fork, you will use the URL of the fork repository, not the main repository.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, saved me a lot of time!!